# Select the most current records from multiple identical rows in the MySQL database

Tags: mysql, unique, distinct

I am working on a product sample inventory system where I track the movement of the products. The status of each product can have a status of "IN" or "OUT" or "REMOVED". Each row of the table represents a new entry, where ID, status and date are unique. Each product also has a serial number.

I need help with a SQL query that will return all products that are **currently** "OUT". If I simply just select `SELECT * FROM table WHERE status = "IN"`, it will return all products that ever had status IN.

Every time product comes in and out, I duplicate the last row of that specific product and change the status and update the date and it will get a new ID automatically.

Here is the table that I have:

```
id | serial_number  | product | color  | date       | status
------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | K0T4N          | XYZ     | silver | 2016-07-01 | IN
 2 | X56Z7          | ABC     | silver | 2016-07-01 | IN
 3 | 96T4F          | PQR     | silver | 2016-07-01 | IN
 4 | K0T4N          | XYZ     | silver | 2016-07-02 | OUT
 5 | 96T4F          | PQR     | silver | 2016-07-03 | OUT
 6 | F0P22          | DEF     | silver | 2016-07-04 | OUT
 7 | X56Z7          | ABC     | silver | 2016-07-05 | OUT
 8 | F0P22          | DEF     | silver | 2016-07-06 | IN
 9 | K0T4N          | XYZ     | silver | 2016-07-07 | IN
10 | X56Z7          | ABC     | silver | 2016-07-08 | IN
11 | X56Z7          | ABC     | silver | 2016-07-09 | REMOVED
12 | K0T4N          | XYZ     | silver | 2016-07-10 | OUT
13 | 96T4F          | PQR     | silver | 2016-07-11 | IN
14 | F0P22          | DEF     | silver | 2016-07-12 | OUT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will give you all the latest records for each `serial_number`

```
SELECT a.* FROM your_table a
LEFT JOIN your_table b ON a.serial_number = b.serial_number AND a.id < b.id
WHERE b.serial_number IS NULL
```

Below query will give your expected result

```
SELECT a.* FROM your_table a
LEFT JOIN your_table b ON a.serial_number = b.serial_number AND a.id < b.id
WHERE b.serial_number IS NULL AND a.status LIKE 'OUT'
```

Comment: That's great. Can you please upvote and accept my answer ;)

Comment: I accepted the answer but it wouldn't let me upvote it becuase I need higher reputation... sorry

Answer (score 1):

There are two good ways to do this. Which way is best,in terms of performance, can depend on various factors, so try both.

```
SELECT
t1.*
FROM table t
LEFT OUTER JOIN table later_t
ON later_t.serial_number = t.serial_number
AND later_t.date > t.date
WHERE later_t.id IS NULL
AND t.status = "OUT"
```

Which column you check from `later_t` for `IS NULL` does not matter, so long as that column is declared `NOT NULL` in the table definition.

The other logically equivalent method is:

```
SELECT
t.*
FROM table t
INNER JOIN (
SELECT
serial_number,
MAX(date) AS date
FROM table
GROUP BY serial_number
) latest_t
ON later_t.serial_number = t.serial_number
AND latest_t.date = t.date
WHERE t.status = "OUT"
```

For each of these queries, I strongly suggest the following index:

```
ALTER TABLE table
ADD INDEX `LatestSerialStatus` (serial_number,date)
```

I use this type of query a lot in my own work, and have the above index as the primary key on tables. Query performance is extremely fast in such cases, for these type of queries.

See also the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html) on this query type.

Comment: thank's for the solution, and thank you for the advice about indexing, I started it and everything works perfectly now